# Python dictionary to CSV rows and colums

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to form a dictionary to a CSV file.

It works, but I have 1 problem I need to set every value on 1 row, but on different columns.
And I can't get it to work to have 1 line of values whit more columns so every value has is own column field.

I simplified the code:

```
dic ={10:[[1,9],'10%','+','01/11/2017',13],6:[[5,1],'20%','+','01/11/2017',14]}
with open('test.csv','a') as file_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(file_csv)
    for key, value in dic.items():
        writer.writerow([key,value[0][0],value[0][1],value[1],value[2],value[3],value[4]])
file_csv.close()
```

---

so i expect exel :

```
A       B       C       D       E       F               G
10      1       9       10%     "+"     01/11/2017      13
6       5       1       20%     "+"     01/11/2017      14
```

and now i have this exel :

```
A                               B        C         D        E     F    G
10,1,9,10%,+,01/11/2017,13
6,5,1,20%,+,01/11/2017,14
```

Comment: it's working fine.

Comment: You just need to configure excel properly when importing your csv file. Set delimiter and quote character.

Comment: Now in my excel file everything is in the same column , so nothing is wrong white the code?

Comment: @Zacha as @Piotr said, when you are importing your `csv` file to Excel, you need to set the `,` as the delimiter.

Comment: oké thank you for the help. i found it.

Comment: If you are up for learning new stuff, pandas is really awesome for these kind of tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
writer = csv.writer(Filecsv,delimiter=";")
```

This should do it (like Piotr Pęczek said). 
Kind regards